# monotouch navigation and tab controllers

Tags: xamarin.ios

Hello i am new to monotouch and i am trying to make an app that has multiple screens and one of my screens can have tabs (tab controller).
So i want to use a navigation controller and a tab controller.

> Can i use a controller inside another?
>   so can my view when created also create a new tab controller? or shall i make a tab root >controller and hide it on my other screens? Also if you can suggest a book or something it >would be nice.
>   thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UINavigationController can pretty much go inside anything.

The problem is that UITabBarControllers kind of need to go in the root of your application.  They probably won't work well being pushed into other UINavigationControllers, and I've had some issues with them in the past.

I would recommend to layout your app with UINavigationControllers and UITableViews listing new screens to go to.  This will probably be less confusing for users also.

UITabBarControllers are great, but I feel like they need to be on the main screen (first part of the app that the user will see).